# If a option is selected from a component/card and on submit button I want to show another component/card and hide the card which has options

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, quasar-framework

````
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md" id="meal">
    <q-card class="my-card">
      <q-card-section>

        <q-form ref="mealPlanForm" class="q-gutter-md">
          <q-radio name="patientType" v-model="patientType" val="Existing Patient" label="Existing Patient" id="opt1"/>
          <q-radio name="patientType" v-model="patientType" val="New Patient" label="New Patient" id="opt2"/>

      <q-card v-if="patientType === 'New Patient'" flat bordered class="q-mt-md ">
        <q-card-section>Patient Data</q-card-section>
          <q-separator />
      <q-card-section class="row q-gutter-sm items-center">
        <q-separator />
        <div class="q-px-sm q-py-xs rounded-borders text-center text-no-wrap">
          <q-radio name="patientType" v-model="patientType" val="addPatient" label="Add Patient to System" />
          <q-radio name="patientType" v-model="patientType" val="MealPlan" label="Continue without adding patient to system" />
        </div>
      </q-card-section>
    </q-card>

    </q-form>

      <div class="row flex-center q-my-md">
        <q-btn @click="showCard = true" label="Continue" type="submit" color="primary"/>
        <basicMealplan v-if="showCard"></basicMealplan>
      </div>

      </q-card-section>
    </q-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import basicMealplan from './mealPlanCard.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    basicMealplan
  },
  setup () {
    // function onChange(){
    //   showCard = true
    // }
    return {
      showCard: ref(false),
      patientType: ref('Existing Patient'),

    }
  }
}
</script>

```[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COD11.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COD11.png)
````

For currently when the continue button is click then second card pops out. I want the code to work out when the first option is selected and continue button is click the first card should be not displayed and only the second card should be seen.

Even though it maybe a no-brainer thing but I and a complete beginner

Comment: not sure what elements you've designated as "first card" and "second card", but if the Continue button sets `showCard = true`, then add a `v-if="!showCard"` to the element you want to hide when the Continue button is clicked (it should only display while showCard is false)

Comment: Your card hierarchy should be `<q-card v-if></q-card><q-card v-else></q-card>`  Your example has the card nested.